# How to query for user story time in Rally

Tags: java, rally

Using Java, I would like to query Rally for the amount of time that user stories in a specific project took to <strike>complete</strike> become "Accepted". I have some familiarity with the Rally API already, and have already used it to gather defect data.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks!

References:
http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitForJava/
https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide

I also have access to the Rally Web Services API Documentation v2.0 at https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking for "Defects" do a query for "HeirarchicalRequirements"

```
QueryRequest ustore = new QueryRequest("hierarchicalrequirement");
ustore.setLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
ustore.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name","Parent","Feature","Blocked","PlanEstimate","ScheduleState","Release","Iteration","Owner","Project"));
ustore.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Feature.Name","=",feature.getName()));
QueryResponse usResp = restApi.query(ustore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Search [rally tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rally) for Lookback API posts. [LBAPI](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual) provides historic data.
Even though LBAPI is language agnostic, [Rally REST Toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava) does not have a built-in support for it. Currently only javascript AppSDK2 has built-in support for it through [snapshotstore](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore).

Unlike Lookback API, WS API gives only the current state of objects. Of course historic data can be gathered from WS API by parsing RevisionHistory,but parsing revisions is expensive and inefficient.
In WS API HierarchicalRequirement has AcceptedDate attribute. This can be accessed directly without having to parse revision history. There is no equivalent for Completed date. You would have to parse revision history to find a revision when a story was set to Completed.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "Completed", I actually meant "Accepted". I'll edit my post to reflect that. So I can get the accepted date, but will it also be possible to get the date it was created or started? That way I can do a calculation on it to get the total time for the story from start/creation to acceptance.

Comment: Yes, there is CreationDate on PersistableObject from which HierarchicalRequirement inherits.